# Number of permutations when there's a pair of identical items

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there's a bag with four balls; color 0 appears once, color 1 appears once, color 2 appears twice.

How many ways are there to draw these balls?

Having done this by hand, I believe there's 12 different options:

| ball1 | ball2 | ball3 | ball4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

The issue here is that I cannot seem to formalize this other than by moving the pair of 1's around (which then leaves me with two possibilities; 0-2 and 2-0).

How can I systematically solve for the number of permutations in this problem?

Comment: Hi Arturo, is it possible that you mean **permutations** rather than combinations? Have a look at this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: Did the wikipedia page also solve your problem?